# A running summary of totals in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Come up against an issue where I want to summarize results in a query.

Example as follows:

```
NAME | FRUIT | PRICE 
-----+-------+------
JOHN | APPLE |  2
JOHN | APPLE |  2
JOHN | APPLE |  2
JOHN | APPLE |  2
DAVE | GRAPE |  3
DAVE | GRAPE |  3
DAVE | GRAPE |  3
```

This is my table at the moment, what i need though is to have a summary of Johns business, like below:

```
NAME | FRUIT | PRICE 
-----+-------+------
JOHN | APPLE |  2
JOHN | APPLE |  2
JOHN | APPLE |  2
JOHN | APPLE |  2
JOHN | TOTAL |  8 
DAVE | GRAPE |  3
DAVE | GRAPE |  3
DAVE | GRAPE |  3
DAVE | TOTAL |  9
```

I have tried to group the information but it does not reflect what i want, plus if John were to have different fruit it would need to sum that up before it sums up the next part and it needs to have a running total for all values in the NAME field as there will be a number of customers.

Any advice would be great

**EDIT**

I have tried using Rollup but I keep getting totals of all values in a seperate column where as I would like to see it as the way it is formatted above

Comment: look into using 'rollup'

Comment: There are few ways to do this, easiest way is to add UNION under your query and have `Select Name, 'Total', SUM(Price) Price from YourTable Group by Name' ... and order by name, price

Comment: @RyanGadsdon Rollup was my first choice actually it only give me a summary of ALL the prices, unless im using it wrong, which wouldnt be a suprise. Thank you though! i will update the Question

Comment: @Veljko89 My issue with UNION is that the amount of values in NAME will change on any given day and could be upto 100 unique values, would a Variable work?

Comment: Make sure you use GROUP BY NAME WITH ROLLUP

Comment: @RyanGadsdon will i be able to have it in rows as opposed to Columns using this method?

Comment: @Nonagon can you post your query and current result please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution with `UNION` and `GROUP BY`.

```
;WITH PricesWithTotals AS
(
    SELECT
        Name,
        Fruit,
        Price
    FROM
        YourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        Name,
        Fruit = 'TOTAL',
        Price = SUM(Price)
    FROM
        YourTable
    GROUP BY
        Name
)
SELECT
    Name,
    Fruit,
    Price
FROM
    PricesWithTotals
ORDER BY
    Name,
    CASE WHEN Fruit <> 'Total' THEN 1 ELSE 999 END ASC,
    Fruit
```

Comment: Thank you @EzLo i will give this a try and update as best i can!

Answer (score 1):

This will get you a running total per customer per fruit:

```
create table #Sales([Name] varchar(20), Fruit varchar(20), Price int)
insert into #Sales([Name], Fruit, Price)
values
('JOHN','APPLE',2),
('JOHN','APPLE',2),
('JOHN','APPLE',2),
('JOHN','APPLE',2),
('DAVE','GRAPE',3),
('DAVE','GRAPE',3),
('DAVE','GRAPE',3)


Select c.*
, SUM(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY c.[Name], c.[Fruit] ORDER BY c.[Name], c.[Fruit] rows between unbounded preceding and current ROW ) as RunningTotal
from #Sales c
order by c.[Name], c.[Fruit] asc

drop table #Sales
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi @GandRalph, the issue is that i want to see the data set in the format in my question which im hoping isnt impossible to do! Thank you though, your solution helps in a different way

Comment: @Nonagon In that case EzLos answer does it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem is `GROUPING SETS`.  However, your rows are not unique.  Alas, so this adds a unique value, just so you can keep your original rows:

```
with t as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from t
     )
select name, ,
       coalesce(fruit, 'Total') as fruit,
       sum(price) as price
from t
group by grouping sets ( (name, fruit, seqnum), (name) )
order by name,
      (case when fruit is not null then 1 else 2 end);
```